# There exists a selfadjoint Hamiltonian operator for any 1-parameter family of unitaries indexed by a positive real?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian

Let $\{U(t)\}_{t\in\mathbb R^{\geq 0}}$ be a family of unitary matrices indexed by $t\in\mathbb R^{\geq 0}$.

The question is:
There exists always a unique Hamiltonian $H$ such that for each $t$, $U(t) = e^{-iHt}$  ?

Comment: Yes, that is essentially the content of the theorem of Stone (which was proven more elegantly by von Neumann, but still keeps only the name of the discoverer, Marshall Harvey Stone).

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for the pointer. We have found the exact theorem: Theorem B from https://doi.org/10.2307%2F1968538

Comment: Did you assume $U(t) U(s)= U(s) U(t)$?

Comment: No. Theorem B in the cite of my previous comment only assume that U(t) is linear and continuous on t.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/250252/50583

Answer (score 1):

Following @DanielC's comment, the result is known as [Stone's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem), first shown as Theorem B in [*"On One-Parameter Unitary Groups in Hilbert Space"*](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F1968538) by Stone.